# Android: calendar.getTimeInMillis() get different value

Tags: android, dialog, alert, alarm

I have one app which over some time get notification on status bar like alarm.
The problem is when the time is met he run perfect, but after this time the alert is launch on some periods, like 5 minutes, 1 hour.

Then I put one (if) to solve the problem, but they never met.

```
   long current_time = System.currentTimeMillis();

  if (current_time == limit_time)
```

This is the full code.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();


        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);

        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,11);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,27);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);


        long current_time = System.currentTimeMillis();


        long limit_time = calendar.getTimeInMillis();



       if (current_time == limit_time){
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyReceiver.class);
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, myIntent, 0);


            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it's different every time, that's the point, when you count in milliseconds its not the same time *now* and *now*

Change your code and use < or > depending on your need instead of == as the computer might skip to check the value you're looking for because it's going to fast so it might go from 1388395620883 to 1388395620892 , it's actually not skipping but it doesn't have time to print or check (or whatever) them all. 
try to print this `System.currentTimeMillis()` in an infinite loop to see how it goes, you'll see it cannot "print that fast"

Comment: I convert `current_time` and `limit_time ` to minutes `if(limit_time_minutes == current_time_minutes)` but they don't want to met when the app is stopped, the alert is activated when I manually run the app.

Comment: Not the best approach to do that I think (use better >= or >=, you're doing an unnecessary operation) . But how did you convert it?, as an int, a float, rounding up? put your code here

Comment: With this I convert the milis to minutes `long current_time_minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(current_time);` I found something interesting. It is look the program don't want to run automatically this operation because is not from the class `Calendar`.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure I understood what you are asking, but

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
```

will get a `Calendar` instance initialized to current date and time, with millisecond precision.

When you set some fields on the calendar, the others are left intact. So, if the last 3 digits in a millisecond stamp are problematic, set them to zero as well:

```
calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
```

And for comparisons of millisecond timestamps it often more useful to use `>=` or `<=` rather than `==`.

Comment: Hey @laalto, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use compare

if (time == limit_time) is causing the issue

set both values to calendar and compare them .[check this for more details](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html)

Comment: I tried with this but nothing happen:  `Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
            
            int compare = calendar.compareTo(calendar1);

            if (compare == 0) `

Comment: Its better to compare date up to minute only you can avoid second precision.